# set ReportParameter value from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I am wondering if I can set value in asp.net page not from code behind page.
like I have code behind like this

```
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(
                new ReportParameter("Year", Request.QueryString["Year"])
                );
```

how can I move it to aspx page.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is but in MVC I simply made a page to submit the parameters to the server then passed those variables to the pageload initialization (like the code you have). Theoretically you could use a textfield and Ajax to do something similar as well. I'm on my phone right now, if I remember, I'll try to formally answer with an example when I get to a computer.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in ASP.net MVC or just ASP.net?

Comment: Thanks you all. I am using web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so when I originally read your question, I understood it to mean that you want the parameter able to be set on the same page as the report. The second time I visited this, I understood it to mean that you just want the parameter able to be set via user-input.

I'm not sure which is the one you want but here goes my answer:

**Parameter values via user-input** (on another page):

**My Page (Parameters.cshtml)**:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @for (Int32 I = 0; I < Report.Parameters.Count; I++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("[" + I + "].PromptString", Report.Parameters[I].PromptString, new { @type = "text", @readonly = "readonly", @tabindex = "-1", @style = "text-align: right; border: 0px ridge black; color: black;" })</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + I + "].ID", Report.Parameters[I].ID, new { @type = "hidden" })
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + I + "].QueryParameter", Report.Parameters[I].QueryParameter, new { @type = "hidden" })
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + I + "].DataType", Report.Parameters[I].DataType, new { @type = "hidden" })
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + I + "].DataSet.ID", Report.Parameters[I].DataSet.ID, new { @type = "hidden" })
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + I + "].IsDisplayParameter", Report.Parameters[I].IsDisplayParameter, new { @type = "hidden" })
                    @Html.CheckBox("[" + I + "].Nullable", Report.Parameters[I].Nullable, new { @class = "hidden" })
                    @Html.TextBox("[" + I + "].Value", "", new { @type = Report.Parameters[I].GetInputType() })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Page** (When viewing it on the site):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="[0].PromptString" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: right; border: 0px ridge black; color: black;" tabindex="-1" type="text" value="Username: "></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[0].ID" type="hidden" value="44">
                    <input name="[0].QueryParameter" type="hidden" value="@Username">
                    <input name="[0].DataType" type="hidden" value="System.String">
                    <input name="[0].DataSet.ID" type="hidden" value="12">
                    <input name="[0].IsDisplayParameter" type="hidden" value="False">
                    <input class="hidden" name="[0].Nullable" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[0].Nullable" type="hidden" value="false">
                    <input name="[0].Value" type="text" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="[1].PromptString" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: right; border: 0px ridge black; color: black;" tabindex="-1" type="text" value="Hide Inactive reports: "></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[1].ID" type="hidden" value="45">
                    <input name="[1].QueryParameter" type="hidden" value="@HideInactive">
                    <input name="[1].DataType" type="hidden" value="System.Boolean">
                    <input name="[1].DataSet.ID" type="hidden" value="12">
                    <input name="[1].IsDisplayParameter" type="hidden" value="True">
                    <input class="hidden" name="[1].Nullable" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[1].Nullable" type="hidden" value="false">
                    <input name="[1].Value" type="checkbox" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**On Form-Submit**: On form submit I submit these parameters and their values to the server as a List.

**Report-Load**:

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Get Report ViewModel from Session
    // Note: SelectedReport is a class I created to simply store the information I needed for a report.
    //      i.e. Its definition, name/desc, dataset information, parameters, etc.
    NMBS.Models.SelectedReport Report = Manager.GetValue(ContextID) as NMBS.Models.SelectedReport;

```
// Load Report Parameters.
// Report.ReportParameters is simply of type List<ReportParameter> See the class below.
ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(Report.ReportParameters);
```

}

**Report-Parameter Class**:
public class ReportParameter
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String PromptString { get; set; }
    public String DataType { get; set; }
    public Int32 Priority { get; set; }
    public String QueryParameter { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsDisplayParameter { get; set; }
    public DataSet DataSet { get; set; }
    public Boolean Nullable { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

This is how I did it in MVC. I know you're using webforms but it shouldn't be a huge change to do this in there. I hope this helps.